# How to do an image to force DIV size when resizing window

Tags: html, image, css, resize

I have 2 divs, one 75% (left) and other 25% (right).

On the right side I have ads with size of 300x250 and when resizing the window, the CSS follow the percentage (75% - 25%) and the ad comes out of the window.

So how to force the image to be inside the right div? In this case I want the priority to 300x250 (right side), so when resizing the window the right side should increase to wrap the ad and the left side should decrease.

```css
.div75 {
 float:left;
 width:75%;
 background:#f00;
}
.div25 {
 float:left;
 width:25%;
 text-align:center;
 background:#ff0;
}
.ad-pic {
 float:left;
 width:31%; /* 3 ads is 31%* and 4 is 23% */
 margin-right:1%;
 margin-left:1%;
 padding-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div75">

<div class="ad-pic">
<img src="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/deb55b_3f92f35116534786adc903246daeddfb.jpg_srz_400_300_75_22_0.50_1.20_0.00_jpg_srz" width="100%" />
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua... </span>
</div>

<div class="ad-pic">
<img src="http://static1.businessinsider.com/image/4bd6f13d7f8b9aa520190300-1200/rutherford-b-hayes-october-4-1822-january-17-1893.jpg" width="100%" />
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua... </span>
</div>

<div class="ad-pic">
<img src="http://static.businessinsider.com/image/82b9b9143b51b9492cde8f00/image.jpg" width="100%" />
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua... </span>
</div>

</div>

<div class="div25">
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/b2/7d/85/b27d85b41b69ddda088358211f387a89.jpg" />
</div>
```

Here is a example:

http://jsfiddle.net/sp571pbk/

Answer (score 1):

You could use css3's `calc()` property, allowing you to make the left div `calc(100% - 300px)` width.

http://jsfiddle.net/sp571pbk/3/

```
.div75 {
    float:left;
    width:calc(100% - 300px);
    background:#f00;
}
.div25 {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#ff0;
}
```

Just make sure you can use it on the browsers you target :
http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc